Upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04
I get the message of a problem most likely with the network. What please, in lay-mans language does this mean and how do I over come it.

Sorry Typo should read to 24.04

Please edit your question instead of posting information in comments. I doubt someone can give you an answer unless you provide more details. We don't know what message you talk about. Please provied terminal output  or a screenshot from the application which give you the message.
